# how toggle all div tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, toggle

how? when click the .button, hide all .body div tags and show just closest .body tag div

my codes first one works, but when click the .button, show .body, but when click again, does't toggle ( show / hide ) that, any more?

How to do it properly?

### Edit : how to change .button > span icon? ( positive or negative )

### Edit : jQuery(this).find('positive').toggleClass('negative'); ?

### Edit (saitho): JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/nL4sxbj0/2/

### HTML

```
<div class="box">

  <div class="header">

    <a href="#" class="button">

      <span class="positive"></span>

    </a>

  </div>

  <div class="body">

  </div>

</div>
```

### CSS

```
.body {
  display:none;
}

.button .positive,
.button .negative {
  width:36px;
  height:36px;
  float:right;
  display:block;
  cursor:pointer;
}

.button .positive {
  background:url('../img/icon-del.png') no-repeat center center / 18px;
}

.button .negative {
  background:url('../img/icon-opn.png') no-repeat center center / 18px;
}
```

### JQUERY

```
jQuery('.button').on('click' ,function(e) {

    e.preventDefault(); // Is this necessary? for <a href="#"></a>

    jQuery('.body').hide(); // Problem is hear i think

    jQuery(this).closest('.box').find('.body').toggle(); 

});
```

### Picture

[image]

Comment: can you post a jsfiddle so we can see it in action?

Comment: Just added a JSFiddle link ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add class `iconbtn` to button span

```
<div class="box">

  <div class="header">

    <a href="#" class="button">

      <span class="iconbtn positive"></span>

    </a>

  </div>

  <div class="body">

  </div>
```

```
jQuery('.button').on('click' ,function(e) {
     e.preventDefault();

     var box = jQuery(this).closest('.box');

     var closestBody = box.find('.body');
     jQuery('.body').not(closestBody).hide(); // Hide all except above div

     jQuery(closestBody).toggle(); // if visible hide it else show it

     jQuery('.iconbtn').removeClass('negative').addClass('positive');     
     var iconBtn = box.find('.iconbtn');

     if (jQuery(closestBody).is(':visible')) {
       iconBtn.removeClass('positive').addClass('negative');
     } else {
       iconBtn.removeClass('negative').addClass('positive');
    }
});
```

[jsFiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/nL4sxbj0/5/)

Comment: this works properly, and how to change, span Icon? Thank You

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that you have:

`jQuery('.body').hide();`

in your `click` callback, that means the `body` div is first being hidden and then `toggle` works as it should - it shows the `div`. There is no way it can hide it though, as before `toggle` you always first hide the `div`

Remove this line and it should work, check it here: [JS Fiddle](https://jsbin.com/derisixabu/edit?html,css,js,output)

Comment: ok, I need to hide all divs and show just closest div? how should be do?